# How to get Params from the URL to the Authentification function? (Python, Flask)

Tags: python, flask, flask-httpauth

I would like to get the Parameter "*organisation*" from the URL into my flask-httpauth password verification function. By now I just can get the value into my normal function:

```
@app.route('/api/<organisation>/admin/todo', methods=['GET'])
@auth_admin.login_required
def get_admin_todo(organisation):
   return jsonify({'organisation': organisation})
```

But I can't get it into the Authentification function:

```
@auth_admin.get_password
def get_password_admin(username):
   organisation = "" #here I would like to have my organisation value
   password = "my pwd"
   return password
```

But I need this parameter for the identification. I want to identify a person by his organisation, username and his password.
I would be very happy if anyone had any ideas.

Thank you very much

snake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `request.view_args['organisation']`:

```
organisation = request.view_args['organisation']
```